# Who will shout first?

Tags: logical-deduction, meta-knowledge

[image]

There are four guys standing in a line. They need to find out which color their hats are. They can't see their own hat color and only can see to the right. They can't see the person behind the seperation wall. If they know their hat color they can shout it and will win a million dollars. If they're wrong they die.

Who shouts and therefore wins the million dollars?

[ I found this puzzle on another site and thought it was worth sharing, not sure if it's allowed ]

Comment: You need to specify the constraint that there are two white and two black hats, and that the people know this

Answer (score 4):

[**Prisoners and hats puzzle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoners_and_hats_puzzle)

The answer is

> 2

Since there are only two hats of each color, 1 is able to deduce his color when 2 and 3 are the same color. Though, in this situation 2 and 3 are different, so 1 doesn't shout. 
2, not hearing 1 shouting, deduces that his hat is of the opposite color of 3 and shouts!

Comment: Sorry i see its a duplicate of http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/four-prisoners-wearing-black-and-white-hats?rq=1 will close it.